# Misleading warning "Missing character: There is no ... in font dsrom10!"

Tags: bm

I'm getting misleading warning of the missing character "q" in a place where I actually see it printed. The output is fine. Problem is in `\widehat{\boldsymbol{\mathfrak{q}}}`. I know that `dsrom10` font has only capital letters (and few more symbols), but tex should not take it at all in `\widehat`. Egregs solution [dsrom skewchar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327004/missing-character-there-is-no-amsmath-bug) doesn't help. From tracing it seems something wrong with `\boldsymbol` font selection. Probably `\bm@mchoice`
takes the latest registered `math version normal` which is `\mathds`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
$\mathds{A}$
$\boldsymbol{\mathfrak{q}}$
$\widehat{\boldsymbol{\mathfrak{q}}} $
\end{document}
```

Warnings:

```
Missing character: There is no q (U+0071) in font dsrom10!
Missing character: There is no q (U+0071) in font dsrom10!
Missing character: There is no q (U+0071) in font dsrom8!
Missing character: There is no q (U+0071) in font dsrom8!
```

Could somebody point me to a global solution. (Re-typesetting the document is not the option).

Comment: Those warnings are innocuous.

Comment: I don't get these warnings. The information is printed to the `.log` but they are not marked as warnings.

Comment: I wouldn't say that. Some times it's really missing glyphs.

Comment: it seems that if you enter the last line as `$\boldsymbol{\widehat{\mathfrak{q}}} $` the warning doesn't appear.  but i can't explain why.

Comment: Barbara, that example is tricky. I waste a lot of time shorting it to minimal from the article.

Comment: there is apparently a problem when `amssymb` (or `amsmath`) is used with `bm`.  this is being looked into.  until there is a solution to that problem, there isn't any way to avoid these "missing character" messages.  i'm afraid that, for now, you'll just have to check them to make sure they aren't significant.